# JSP execute select query does not display results

Tags: mysql, jsp

I can't find the reason why the result won't print.

Need help from experts. Also is it okay to use `getString` even if its data type in `mysql` is int.

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%

try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        //out.println("DRIVER NOT FOUND");
    }

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet2 = null;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eenrol", "root", "");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet2 = statement.executeQuery("SELECT IDNumber FROM student where status='pending'");
    } catch (Exception sql) {
        response.sendRedirect("studProfilePage.jsp");
    }
    try {
            ArrayList studList = new ArrayList();
            int rs = 0;
            while(resultSet2.next()){
                rs = resultSet2.getInt("IDNumber");
                    studList.add(rs);
                    request.setAttribute("pend", rs);
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("studProfilePage.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

Comment: Need to see `studProfilePage.jsp` also more helpful if you show error logs !!! Yes you can use `getString()` even if its data type in mysql is int. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you shouldnt be writing the sql queries in JSP it should be at DAO layer so try to avoid in future.
2. I dont see print statement in your code so that may be the issue. Anyway if you
   want to print in JSP then use out.println( Thanks Hope it helps.